# Run Dates In Informatica

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter, informatica-powerexchange

I have a senerio where i need to pull the records  of the previous month on the first of the month( example: pull the data of Jan month data on first of feb).

so I was planning to put it in the same session as the first "target load plan"
sq  --> exp to populate mapping variables (if all zeros, use previous moth else use parm values)  -->   target with 000000   then in post session, delete original parm and rename new one .

but implementing it is a big task for me ,i am unable to  think how to srtart the porcess  can someone please help me do the above process.

Thanks ,
 Kiran

Answer (score 0):

You can use **ADD_TO_DATE** function:

```
Syntax - ADD_TO_DATE (date_column, format, value)
```

Consider your system date is Feb 1st, now you need to pull last month's data:

```
ADD_TO_DATE (01-02-2016, 'MM',-1)
```

Here date have been provided and in the format **'MM'** with value **-1** is given. -1 decreases the value based on the format. So **MM** is a month and February month will be pointed to January. Like wise you can provide for date and year as well (**'DD' & 'YYYY'**)

Use **IIF** function to get data,

```
IIF (Your_column = 0,ADD_TO_DATE (01-02-2016, 'MM',-1),your_param_value)
```

Use this in Filter or Router Transformation

Comment: Any issue, feel free to ask

Comment: Hi , your logics works fine but my intension is to apply loagic in such a way that if any issue  ouccrs and if my mappings is missed to run that month , and i want to go back and run i need to make changes in date and promtoe all over, instead was thinking is there a  way i can do it automatically? every time set the  target with 000000 then in post session, delete original parm and rename new one .